# Postgres selecting current hour data

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres database with a table 'token' and it has 'token_id' and its generated time

```
token_id | generated_time
196618   | 2016-10-15 01:02:48.963
196619   | 2016-10-15 01:02:50.569
196620   | 2016-10-15 01:03:12.931
196621   | 2016-10-15 02:03:17.037
196622   | 2016-10-15 02:22:55.782
196623   | 2016-10-15 02:24:57.477
196624   | 2016-10-15 03:23:00
```

What I want to do is selecting current hour data from the table for example if current datetime is **2016-10-15 01:30:15** then i want to select all the data between **2016-10-15 01:00:00 and 2016-10-15 02:00:00**

thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say [`date_trunc('hour')`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) might be of help here, e.g.

```
select token_id, generated_time
from token
where generated_time between date_trunc('hour', current_timestamp)
    and date_trunc('hour', current_timestamp + interval '1 hour')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `date_trunc()`:

```
where generated_time >= date_trunc('hour', current_timestamp)
```

That actually assumes no future times in your table.  A more specific answer is:

```
where generated_time >= date_trunc('hour', current_timestamp) and
      generated_time < date_trunc('hour', current_timestamp) + interval '1 hour'
```