# Create trigger in postgres / CRON

Tags: php, postgresql, server, triggers

Im working with postgresql and i've never created a trigger/Procedure before.

I have a table that contains a activity, status and the id of one person.

What i need is something like this:
Suppose that lunch_time is a column From table Person and contains data like: 11:00am.

`When now() = lunch_time then UPDATE status.`

I've been looking for an example using cron that executes an php script every minute but i'm afraid of supercharger the server.

There is one easy way? Thanks guys.

Comment: Simple solution is run a CRON every minute. Not sure how a database trigger is relevant if I am understanding your question. What is your question more specifically?

Comment: @ficuscr I wanna know if there is a way to make a trigger in postgres that execute that action ( Update the row where status = X to Y) when now() = lunch_time without make a CRON.  I'm a dev in a ERP company and i'm afraid of a CRON  supercharges the server cause there is too many rows to update.

Comment: Database triggers execute when certain events occur like insert, update or delete. The `now() = lunch_time` doesn't seem like a good candidate for an insert trigger. The database will not evaluate everything every second to see if a criteria has been met.

Comment: No. There is no way to make a trigger for this. A trigger is **only** fired in response to some predefined action, the passage of time is not one of those actions. You can create a procedure or function (depending on your version) that runs the necessary DML That routine can be called. That procedure is called by the php script which is initiated by cron - but that seems like a little overkill; just run the DML from php.  As far as the server goes, test it, unless you 100Ks updated every minute there should not be any issue.

Comment: @Belayer and ficuscr, thanks for helping. I will make a cron to update/insert the data.

Comment: You might use a scheduler like `pg_timetable` for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you have a table `T1 (id , status , activity , person_id)` & Person table as `Person( person_id , lunch_time)` . Instead of updating the data every minute you can simply create a view and then select that [view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createview.html).
The view should look something like this :

```
CREATE VIEW T1_with_lunch_status AS
SELECT T1.id ,
       case when now() = lunch_time then 'Its lunch time' else 'Working Time' end as status,
T1.activity , T1.person_id
FROM T1
INNER JOIN Person P on (P.person_id = T1.person_id) ;
```

Please note that I'm using stricter join, you should use the join type according to your db design and condition like `now() = lunch_time` will return true only when the exact time matches so you may consider truncate/trim time into minutes/hour as per your [convenience](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40063165/7789871).

Comment: Nice! This should work. 
As a matter of fact i have a table named 'Work_time' who have a child one, this child one contains all periods (column start 08:00, end 12:00 as one row, start 13:30 end 18:00 as other row), so I can select `case now() between start and end THEN 'Lunch time' else 'Working'`

Comment: Thinking about this solution, it works but i'll make a cron because a need to insert some "log" to this activity. Thanks for helping man.